# Silverlight export canvas to image

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I have Expression blend 4 and I want to create a button to export to an image file the current view in silverlight

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a question as much as just asking for an implementation. Look into WriteableBitmap. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can render the Canvas to a WriteableBitmap and use this as the Source of an Image control:

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(myCanvas, null);
myImageControl.Source = wb;
```